# wait until the page is loaded

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

In Robot Framework, does any keyword in any library implement this? **Open Browser** and **Go To**  just go to the requested URL but don't wait until the page document is fully loaded.

Comment: you decide when the page is fully loaded, depending on what this constitutes for you, you need to add additional verification steps.

Comment: please have a look at my answer and provide me with some feedback so that we could close this issue for you and for anyone who might come across this in future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [this discussion](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/issues/107). You don't really need to wait for anything apart from Ajax. 
In case you are using Angular, have a look at [extendedselenium2library](https://github.com/rickypc/robotframework-extendedselenium2library) that implements waiting for Angular actions with every keyword.

If you are not using Angular, but you know which Ajax action you expect will fire before you can proceed with your test, have a [Wait Until Page Contains Element](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Wait%20Until%20Page%20Contains%20Element) or [Wait Until Element Is Visible](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Wait%20Until%20Element%20Is%20Visible) keyword with a selector for an element that is specific for your ajax request.